# How to launch application on swipe in corners of android home screen or it may be any screen like lazy swipe

Tags: android, swipe, circular-list, android-controls

I am developing an app like [Lazy Swipe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lazyswipe)

how to launch the app like this from bottom/top corners of screen and how to implement circular scrolling .

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to use pull to refresh listview for lazy scrolling for getting to few records.
also i using a library for it.
you refer to this link.
Here's [ https://github.com/shontauro/android-pulltorefresh-and-loadmore ]

```
lvnewDealTab
            .setOnLastItemVisibleListener(new OnLastItemVisibleListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLastItemVisible() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "End of List!",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    count = count + 1;
                    lvnewDealTab.setMode(Mode.DISABLED);
                    if (Done == true) {
                        lvnewDealTab.setMode(Mode.DISABLED);
                        lvnewDealTab.onRefreshComplete();
                    } else if (Favaorite == true) {
                        // Favaorite = false;
                        lvnewDealTab.setMode(Mode.DISABLED);
                        lvnewDealTab.onRefreshComplete();

                    } else if (NearBy == true) {

                    } else if (All == true) {
                        // GetEventOperationNew("0", "0", "" + count);
                    }
                    // Check The Total Number of Deals...
                    if (TotalDeal.equals(TotalDeal)) {
                         // Calling to services.
                         GetEventOperationNew("0", "0", "" + count);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                                "Total Deals Completed" + TotalDeal,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

at Last Item Visible to put to code for the getting more record.

Comment: thanks for answering but i am not able to get your code because the given link is expires i think so!! please give me some other link or info.

Comment: @surendrasingh I have the solve the problem to not open the link so Now the Try.

Answer (score 0):

I think circular scroll must use some of Samsung magic
 http://developer.samsung.com/s-pen-sdk/samples/Circle-Launcher